# Using Value of Option in select in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In the following:

```
<select id="test">
<option value="1">Test One</option>
<option value="2">Test Two</option>
</select>
```

I want is, When i select the option, The value of selected option should appear in input box. Like when i click Test One, the input box should say 1 as selected
Is it possible to do this in Vue?

Comment: Exactly that scenario is used as an example in the [manual](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select)

Answer (score 2):

You have to used `v-model` to get the selected item from `<select>`

```
 <select v-model="selected">
      <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
      <option>A</option>
      <option>B</option>
 </select>
 <span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>
```

In **Javascript**

```
new Vue({
  el: '...',
  data: {
    selected: ''
  }
})
```

I hope you got what you want!

Comment: like it's <option value="we">A</option> , I need select to show "we" when selected.. Inside the dropdown box, not in seperate variable

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using the `@change` event handler

```
<select @change="handleChange">
  <option 
    v-for="item in options"
    :value="item.value"
    v-text="item.letter"
  />
</select>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    selected: undefined,
    options: [
      { letter: 'A', value: '1' },
      { letter: 'B', value: '2' },
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    handleChange({ target: { value } }) {
      this.selected = value
    }
  },
})
```

Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/caseyjoneal/apg1x9un/16/)